# Amazon pay magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.2.4, amazon-payment

I have configured amazon pay in my site and it is working fine with both login and payment.

The query I have is , Why amazon payment is  separated with other payment methods in checkout page?

it is not included with other payment methods . So it creates confusion for user .

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for this is that Amazon Pay is a 'checkout method', not a 'payment method'. So in contrast to a usual payment method, it provides the user the possibility to select an address that is stored within his Amazon account, so the user doesn't need to enter this information manually on the regular checkout page.

Comment: Thanks.. any help in modifying as payment method.. when I used this module in m1 .. amazon pay is used as payment option but not in m2

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really possible at the moment. You could modify the checkout page to host an Amazon Pay button on the 'Review & Payments' view, but that would jeopardize the information that the user has entered before (name, shipping address) as this would be overwritten by the information in the Amazon  account. For this reason, the Amazon Pay button sits on the cart page and on the beginning of the checkout page so that users can just straight into the Amazon Pay checkout.

Comment: Thank you for the information.. but my question is why the property working on magento 1 is not in magento 2